# UWP Get Clicked Item in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm sure this has been asked before, however I cannot find the appropriate answer.

I am using an ItemTemplate to display a list of users, this list consists of StackPanels with user details. How can I get the user object that I clicked on?

Current code:

```
<GridView Name="usersList">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel PointerPressed="UserClicked">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Forename}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

This is being populated via an async API call:

```
usersList.ItemsSource = null;
var task = Users.UserAsync<User>();
usersList.ItemsSource = await task;
```

How can I capture the User object that has been clicked on PointerPressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
    private void UserClicked(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        User clickedOnUser = (sender as StackPanel).DataContext as User;
    }
```

This approach is more direct than the one using `usersList.SelectedItem`, so I recommend sticking with it. E.g., it will work if you set `SelectionMode="None"` for the GridView, whereas the approach based on `usersList.SelectedItem` won't.

Also, as Sean O'Neil rightfully noticed, you might want to use `Tapped` event instead of `PointerPressed` for the most general case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use GridView.SelectedItem to reference the object you want when you click on it.

```
private void UserClicked_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     var whatYouWant = usersList.SelectedItem;
   }
```

Comment: Also with UWP you should use the Tapped event instead of PointerPressed unless you have a specific reason not to.